# Using a table within a RegionPlot3D to plot multiple cubes

Tags: plotting, regions, 3d-printing

Here's some code that will produce a cube:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  x > 0 && x < 1 && y > 0 && y < 1 && z > 0 && z < 1,
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

What I'm hoping to figure out is a way to loop the code and creating several cubes, say 2 units apart.  Essentially changing the equations to

```
x > 0 + m && x < 1 + m && y > 0 + m && y < 1 + m && z > 0 + m && z < 1 + m
```

where `m` goes from 0 to 8 by 2's --- `{m, 0, 8, 2}`.

I want to use equations instead of `Cuboid`. Also, I don't want to have to write separate equations for each cube. Once I know how to do this, I think I can figure out the rest of what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a table of the defining inequalities and combine them with `Or`. Like so.

```
RegionPlot3D[
  Or @@ 
    Table[
      x > 0 + m && x < 1 + m && y > 0 + m && y < 1 + m && z > 0 + m && z < 1 + m, 
      {m, 0, 8, 2}],
  {x, 0, 11}, {y, 0, 11}, {z, 0, 11}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Translate.html) on the graphics primitives produced by `RegionPlot3D`:

```
rp = RegionPlot3D[x > 0 && x < 1 && y > 0 && y < 1 && z > 0 && z < 1, 
  {x, 0, 11}, {y,  0, 11}, {z, 0, 11}, PlotPoints -> 150, Mesh -> 3];

translations = Table[{m, m, m}, {m, 0, 8, 2}];
MapAt[Translate[#, translations] &, rp, {1}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Graphics3D[Translate[rp[[1]], translations], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> PlotRange[rp]]
```

> same picture

You can also use a combination of [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) and [`TranslationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TranslationTransform.html):

```
Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[rp[[1]], TranslationTransform /@ translations]]
```

> same picture